# JavaScript object inheritance issue

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I'm a beginner with JavaScript Objects and Prototypes and trying to develop my first " multi-level inherited" JS Objects, an unexpected issue came up.
This is my code:

```
var Utils = function () {};
Utils.prototype = {
    sayHelloGeneral: function(){
        console.log('hello');
    }
};

var FormTools = function () {
    Utils.call(this);
    this.fields = [];
};
FormTools.prototype = Object.create(Utils.prototype);
FormTools.prototype.constructor = FormTools;
FormTools.prototype.sayHelloForm= function (fields) {
    console.log('hello form');
};

function GroupManager(value) {
    FormTools.call(this);

    this.val = typeof values === 'undefined' ? 1 : value;
};
GroupManager.prototype = Object.create(FormTools.prototype);
GroupManager.prototype.constructor = GroupManager;
GroupManager.prototype.helloGroupManager= function (givenValue) {
    console.log('Hello group manager');
};
```

Why when I try to call the group manager, it prints only the sayHelloGeneral function?

```
var GM = new GroupManager;

GM.sayHelloGeneral(); //->ok
GM.helloGroupManager(); //--> ok
GM.sayHelloForm(); //->sayHelloForm is not a function
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gvhmfoux/

Comment: Working fine for me..where is your `sayhello()`?

Comment: Sorry it was `sayHelloGeneral`. Fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working fine. See the snippet below

```js
var Utils = function () {};
Utils.prototype = {
    sayHelloGeneral: function(){
        console.log('hello');
    }
};

var FormTools = function () {
    Utils.call(this);
    this.fields = [];
};
FormTools.prototype = Object.create(Utils.prototype);
FormTools.prototype.constructor = FormTools;
FormTools.prototype.sayHelloForm= function (fields) {
    console.log('hello form');
};

function GroupManager(value) {
    FormTools.call(this);

    this.val = typeof values === 'undefined' ? 1 : value;
};
GroupManager.prototype = Object.create(FormTools.prototype);
GroupManager.prototype.constructor = GroupManager;
GroupManager.prototype.helloGroupManager= function (givenValue) {
    console.log('Hello group manager');
};


var GM = new GroupManager;

//GM.sayhello(); //->ok---> should be sayHelloGeneral()
GM.sayHelloGeneral();
GM.helloGroupManager(); //--> ok
GM.sayHelloForm(); //->Works fine too
```

Comment: Thanks guys! I realised that the problem was in my code
`FormTools.prototype.sayHelloForm` was `FormTools.prototypesayHelloForm`.
Of course above it's just an example and my code is far bigger than my silly example :) Thanks a lot